# how do I parse this XML data and get the exact result?

Tags: php

**strong text**I have the following XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MediaContainer friendlyName="MyContainer" identifier="container2" machineIdentifier="sadas6d54a6s54d65a4sd" totalSize="82" size="82">
<User id="123456" title="someEmail@yahoo.com" username="someEmail@yahoo.com" email="someEmail@yahoo.com" recommendationsPlaylistId="" thumb="nothing" protected="0" home="0" allowTuners="0" allowSync="0" allowCameraUpload="0" allowChannels="0" allowSubtitleAdmin="0" filterAll="" filterMovies="" filterMusic="" filterPhotos="" filterTelevision="" restricted="0">
  <Server id="000001" serverId="000001" machineIdentifier="sadas6d54a6s54d65a4sd" name="none" lastSeenAt="1596238173" numLibraries="5" allLibraries="0" owned="1" pending="0"/>
</User>
<User id="654321" title="myUser" username="myUser" email="anotherEmail@gmail.com" recommendationsPlaylistId="" thumb="nothing" protected="0" home="0" allowTuners="0" allowSync="0" allowCameraUpload="0" allowChannels="0" allowSubtitleAdmin="0" filterAll="" filterMovies="" filterMusic="" filterPhotos="" filterTelevision="" restricted="0">
  <Server id="000001" serverId="000001" machineIdentifier="sadas6d54a6s54d65a4sd" name="none" lastSeenAt="1596238173" numLibraries="5" allLibraries="0" owned="1" pending="0"/>
</User>
</MediaContainer>
```

How would I parse this in such a way that if I wanted to get the id of the user by searching for the user's email?

For example if I were to parse this data and then search for the email **someEmail@yahoo.com** I would get back the ID **123456**.
If I search for **anotherEmail@gmail.com** I would get back the ID **654321**.

The following code only puts everything into an array but I'm not sure how I can search in that array using an email and get that unique ID out:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($myXML, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: `$xml = simplexml_load_string($myXML), "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
` would throw a syntax error. Please provide actual reproducible code.

Comment: I edited the code. $myXML is the sample XML content I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `json_encode`/`json_decode` isn't very good with XML and if you use XPath it can be easier to search (although can sometime take time to learn).

This uses an XPath expression (for example) of `//User[@email="anotherEmail@gmail.com"]`.  This means any `<User>` element with the `email` attribute (as it starts with `@`) equal to the string you are searching for.

As `xpath()` returns a list of matches, use `[0]` to just use the first one...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($myXML, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);

$email = "anotherEmail@gmail.com";

$user = $xml->xpath('//User[@email="'.$email.'"]')[0];
echo $user['id']."=>".$user->Server['machineIdentifier'].PHP_EOL;
```

which with the sample data gives...

```
654321=>sadas6d54a6s54d65a4sd
```

I have just displayed a couple of details from the data to show how to use the values in SimpleXML.

Answer (score 1):

Get the user data from the parsed array with the `User` index. And then, you can iterate through that array to form up a new array which would store the required IDs against the corresponding email IDs.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($myXML, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

$users = $array['User'];

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $id[$user['@attributes']['email']] = $user['@attributes']['id'];
}

echo $id['someEmail@yahoo.com'];
```

Comment: Thank you, this works but I got an undefined index email for the following line `$id[$user['@attributes']['email']] = $user['@attributes']['id'];`

Comment: With the XML present in the question, it doesn't throw any error. Is the original XML structure exactly same?

Comment: I see. I'm using `file_get_contents` to grab the XML because its not a local xml file, it's a response from an API call. I wonder if that is why its erroring

Comment: I have marked your answered as accepted since your code does work the way it's meant to, I probably just have the format messed up by using `file_get_contents` on a URL